# How can the use of "-aeus" as an adjective suffix in "Herculaeus" be explained?

Tags: greek, medieval-latin, adjective, suffixes, spoken-language

Apparently, the English word "Herculean" has an old spelling variant "Herculæan". This seems to correspond to a Latin variant of the adjective "herculeus/[Hercŭlĕus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DHerculeus)" spelled "Herculæus" (example: "Magnetem qui **Herculæus** vocatur ubique dispersit, quo nullus est admirabilior, aut utilior lapis in rerum natura." –*[Universæ naturæ theatrum](https://books.google.com/books?id=q04rNlPQnJcC&pg=PA243&lpg=PA243&dq=Hercul%C3%A6us&source=bl&ots=qdYbqNRqMG&sig=57cRB2s3wqOz0kEvMXfEL4JgSEw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj35uKpwvHWAhWh64MKHeveDNYQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Hercul%C3%A6us&f=false),* Jean Bodin, 1596).

I am a little confused by this; I think I understand the formation of the more commonly found "Hercŭlĕus" (correct me if I'm wrong, it seems to be "Hercŭl-" as in "Hercul-is" or "Hercul-em" + the adjectival suffix -ĕus), but I'm not sure if "Herculæus" should just be considered an error, or has some basis to it that I can't currently see.

I know that in medieval Latin, there was a lot of interchange between spellings with "e", "æ" and "œ", so a word might be spelled with any of these with no regard to its etymology. However, I am not entirely sure if that's the whole explanation for the use of "Herculæus" as an adjective.

I know that there are a number of Latin adjectives that did end in etymological "aeus", ultimately coming from Greek adjectives in *-αιος* (such as *[trochaeus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dtrochaeus)* from *τροχαῖος*). As far as I can tell, the "a"/alpha in *-aeus* adjectives originates from the thematic vowel of the first declension, but what I don't know is to what extent this suffix may have been able to be applied analogically to nouns of other declensions. (Also, I know there were similar adjectives in Greek terminating in *-ειος,* Latin *-ēus~ῑus,*, which seem to be formed when an "e"-like vowel came before the adjective suffix. So the Greek name of Hercules, *Ἡρακλῆς,* was the source of the word *ἡράκλειος* that became Latin *Heraclius.*)

In spoken Latin, at least, I would expect there to be a difference in stress between "Herculĕus", stressed on the antepenult, and "Herculaeus", stressed on the penult. But maybe these rules aren't relevant when dealing with medieval Latin. I was wondering if if the "ae" spelling is used in any texts from a period when Latin was still a spoken language, and if so, if that should be taken as evidence for analogical extension of *-aeus* as an adjective suffix, rather than just variation in the letters used to spell the *-ĕus* adjective suffix. Also, if there are other words where "-aeus" is suffixed to a non-first-declension noun like this, I would be interested in knowing about them.

Answer (score 4):

The adjective Herculeus is well attested in Classical Latin. I think “Herculaeus” is merely a bad spelling in Mediaeval or Humanistic Latin.

Comment: I would add that there appear to be [no classical attestations](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=herculae) of anything containing *Herculae-*.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the answer that fdb provided to my question is completely correct; I just wanted to add some relevant information that I discovered recently when I was studying the [inflection of nouns (particularly names) ending in *-ēs*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9283).

#### Nouns/names ending in *-es*

Many names ending in *-es* come from Greek nouns of the first declension (which means that from an etymological perspective, they are built on a stem ending in "a"). Greek masculine nouns of the first declension end in *-ης* or *-ας.* Not all Greek masculine nouns ending in *-ης* belonged to the first declension; some (including  *Ἡρακλῆς*, in fact) belonged to the third declension.

The declension of a name in Latin does not necessarily correspond to the declension of the corresponding name in Greek. In Latin, names ending in *-es* were usually declined as third-declension nouns (with genitive singular forms in *-is*), regardless of whether they came from Greek names of the first or third declension.

However, masculine names ending in *-es* did sometimes take some non-third-declension forms:

- masculine names ending in *-es* sometimes had second-declension genitive singular forms in *-i*. It seems like this might be related in some way to the use of *-ου* in Greek as a termination for the genitive singular of masculine first-declension nouns. That said, there isn't a perfect correspondence between the existence of a Greek genitive singular in *-ου* and a Latin genitive singular in *-i*: *Diomedes,* from the Greek third-declension noun *Διομήδης, Διομήδους,* had a genitive singular form in *-i* alongside a regular third-declension genitive singular form in *-is.*
- masculine names ending in *-es* sometimes had Greek-style accusative singular forms in *-en* (*-ēn*).

#### The name *Hercules*

Currently, it seems plausible to me that the spelling "Herculæus" is related to the use of *-ης* as a termination for Greek first-declension masculine nouns, even though (as mentioned above) Greek *Ἡρακλῆς* is not a first-declension noun.

The Latin name *Hercules* is ultimately from Greek, but apparently not a direct borrowing. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hercules#Latin) says that the Latin form *Hercules* comes from an Etruscan form "Hercle". Although *Hercules* seems to have a somewhat complicated and variable declension, it is not classified as a first-declension noun in any of its forms. But in the nominative singular, it does end the same way as a first-declension noun like *Hermes.*

Greek first-declension nouns sometimes had derivatives spelled with *ae* in Latin: the [Lewis and Short entry on *Hermes*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=Hermes) mentions the related word *Hermaeum,* and from the Greek name *Δίρκη,* there was the Latin adjective *Dircaeus*. I think that the spelling *Herculæus* might have been used partly because of analogy with forms like those.