# How did "glutaeus/gluteus" come from Greek "gloutos"? Would "glutiaeus" be more correct?

Tags: greek, contemporary-latin, adjective, morphology, suffixes

In anatomy, the muscles of the buttocks are referred to collectively as the "[glut(a)eal muscles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluteal_muscles)" in English, and are individually given the following Latin names: *glut(a)eus maximus, glut(a)eus medius* and *glut(a)eus minimus.*

The noun "glutaeus" does not appear to exist in Classical or Medieval Latin. The Oxford English Dictionary (OED)'s earliest citation for it in English is from 1681. The OED says the etymology of English "glut(a)eus is "< modern Latin *glūtæus, glūtēus,* < Greek *γλουτός* rump, buttock." This entry apparently was first published in 1900 and has not yet been fully updated. The American Heritage Dictionary says English *glut(a)eus* is from "New Latin *glūteus,* from Greek *gloutos,* buttock," omitting a macron over the E.

Neither of these dictionaries describe the morphological derivation, so I'm wondering how exactly *gluteus/glutaeus* was formed from *γλουτός.* It seems like it would have been most straightforward to latinize *γλουτός* as *glutus.* Perhaps that didn't happen because *[glutus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=glutus)* was a preexisting Latin adjective meaning something else. But I don't really understand why the ending *-aeus* (or maybe *-ēus* or *-eus*) occurs in *glutaeus.*

The only idea I have is that, according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B3%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%85%CF%84%CF%8C%CF%82), Greek *γλουτός* had a variant neuter plural form *γλουτᾰ́*. So my thought is that maybe *glutaeus* can be analyzed as *gluta* + *-eus.* But using a neuter plural form as the base of a Latin derived adjective seems a bit dubious to me. I guess another possibility, based on the AHD's "glūteus" and the answer to my earlier question about *[Herculeus](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/how-can-the-use-of-aeus-as-an-adjective-suffix-in-herculaeus-be-explained)* and its late variant form *Herculaeus,* is that *glutaeus* is simply an irregular spelling variant of *glut-* + the Latin adjective suffix *-ĕus.* But the OED entry from 1900 seems to have been written by somebody who was convinced the word was stressed on the penultimate syllable, which suggests that this syllable was thought of as having a long vowel in Latin (the OED only gives the English pronunciation as /ɡl(j)uːˈtiːəs/, although the AHD says it can be stressed on either the first or the second syllable).  I wonder if the vowel came to be thought of as long just due to analogy with Latin words that ended in *-aeus* or *-ēus* for etymological reasons.

Setting aside the matter of *-aeus* vs. *-ēus* vs, *-ĕus,* why would an adjectival suffix be used in this context? Should I think of *glutaeus/gluteus* as an adjective modifying an implied substantive noun *musculus*? On Vicipedia, the article for the "Gluteus maximus muscle" is titled "[Musculus glutaeus maximus](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musculus_glutaeus_maximus)".

---

I thought to do a Google search of "glutea" to see if it has been used as an adjective modifying a feminine substantive, and I found the following examples in *[Elsevier's Dictionary of Medicine and Biology: in English, Greek, German, Italian, and Latin](https://books.google.com/books?id=lCKRIT-7X6UC&pg=PA774&dq=%22glutea%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieob-T7IPZAhXRrFkKHd_fBP4Q6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22glutea%22&f=false),* by G. Konstantinidis (2005):

> Anterior gluteal line *n,* linea glutea anterior
>   *TA;* linea glutealis anterior *n*
>
> *g* πρόσθια **γλουτιαία** γραμμή *f -ής*
>   
> *i* linea glutea anteriore *f*

(p. 100)

Interestingly, it looks like in Greek, the adjective derived from *γλουτός* has the form *γλουτιαίος*, which I think would correspond to Latin "glūtiaeus". But I haven't found much evidence of the Latin-alphabet spelling *glutiaeus* being used, although I was able to find one example of "der M. glutiaeus maximus" used in a German text (*[Einführung in die physikalische Anatomie, Part 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=jkM9AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=glutiaeus&source=bl&ots=FEskjSHksj&sig=lmr7LFMvFzOC2fKJSwLCGw2hSxI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9tYen7oPZAhXHrVkKHXEVCZwQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=glutiaeus&f=false),*
By Hermann Triepel, 1908, p. 86-87.

I also found a text that seems to suggest *glutiaeus* would somehow be a better formation than *glut(a)eus.* *[Medical Greek: Collection of Papers on Medical Onomatology and a Grammatical Guide to Learn Modern Greek](https://books.google.com/books?id=eV8SAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=%22glutiaeus%22&source=bl&ots=Oq_EBPFJIm&sig=6N8yxvryO_nDG-Tp12NhEAnO06c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT5_nJ74PZAhUvwlkKHZfTA7kQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22glutiaeus%22&f=false),* by Achilles Rose (1908) contains "Memorial on the Anatomical Nomenclature of the Anatomical Society", presented at its 22nd meeting on April 22, 1908, by Dr. Hermann Triepel, Professor of Anatomy, University of Breslau. Triepel says

> It is a fact established long ago that the anatomical technical language is a playground for barbarisms, ungainly words and even expressions which are an offense against elementary rules of word-formation. (p. 179)

[...]

> Further are to be mentioned a number of adjectives of B N A which habe [sic] been found from Greek nouns and to which the ending eus has been attached, as carpeus, laryngeus, oasophageus [sic], etc. Here the correct ending (again according to Papaioannou) is mostly -icus (-ικος), sometimes -ius (-ιος) or -iaeus (-αιος). (p. 187)

This is followed by a list of words that Triepel thinks are "not free of objection" accompanied by "such terms which, according to my opinion, might be substituted. P., in parentheses, when added to the latter, means Papaioannou." That list includes "glutaeus glutiaeus (P.)." (p. 189).

If anyone can explain exactly why the suffix "ιαιος" apparently is considered correct in this context in Greek, I would appreciate it.